# Wordpress shortcode to get next post in taxonomy returns nothing

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I'm trying to make shortcodes to return a link to the previous and next posts of a particular category in a custom taxonomy ( slug = home-category).

Here's the code I've been working with:

```
    add_shortcode( 'newnext', 'next_shortcode' );
    add_shortcode( 'newprev', 'prev_shortcode' );

    function next_shortcode($atts) {
        return get_next_post_link( '%link', '%title', true, '', 'home-category' ); 
        }
    function prev_shortcode($atts) {
        return get_previous_post_link( '%link', '%title', true, '', 'home-category' );
        }
```

If I place

```
    echo get_previous_post_link( '%link', '%title', true, '', 'home-category' );
    echo get_next_post_link( '%link', '%title', true, '', 'home-category' );
```

into the php theme file, the code works fine. Also, if I use

```
     echo do_shortcode('[newprev]');
     echo do_shortcode('[newnext]');
```

it works fine. However, when I place the shortcodes [newprev][newnext] in the WordPress editor, I get nothing.

Is there some reason this would run from a page template file, but not from inside a posts content?

Comment: make sure, that you placed shortcodes into `text editor`, but not into `visual editor`

Comment: also, you can debug your shortcode by https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/289925/133553 answer. it may help you

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan placing the shortcode in text vs visual makes no difference. Also, followed the link you posted and the shortcodes do show up in the list as available.

Comment: ok. another question. in which `php template` you put the code( you mentioned that it's working in that case )??

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan single.php